# How to get values and textContents of unknown ids and classes in JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

Lets say there are some words or numbers on the website in front of me. I want to make a program that will take those specific words/numbers and change them to something else. Currently, I'm going about doing this using a google extension and coding some JS as a content script. I have been trying to figure out a way for so long. I want it to be general and work on multiple websites as I can't hard-code the ids and classes that point to the values (that I need) for every single website.

I have tried querySelectorAll, document.someMethod, and even window.find() to no avail.

Here are some other thoughts I had that might help you answer my question.

Is there a way to get the HTML code from the website and turn it into an array, loop through the document and use if statements to find what specific words and numbers I need, then finally change them using my JS code? What about just taking out all of the ids and classes from the HTML and doing a check to see if it has anything to do with the specific values I want.

main.js (content script)

```
// How do I generalize querySelectorAll to take every instance of IDS or class names that follow a specific pattern? Lets say I wanted to change the values of each element in the HTML code that had IDs related to the string "titles". 
ids = document.querySelectorAll('')
```

If you need clarification or details please ask and I will give it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this codebase for a chrome extension should be able to help you get on the right track: https://github.com/mark-monteiro/drumpfinator/blob/master/src/inject/inject.js

It does basically what you are trying to do. It takes all instances of the word [Donald Trump via regex](https://github.com/mark-monteiro/drumpfinator/blob/master/src/inject/inject.js#L60) and replaces that with some random funny adjective.

From that example you can use regex or some array to figure out what words you need and replace them with what words you like, perhaps using a key value object.